# Intellij - worksheet can't find class

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have a class defined in a file Rational.scala in src\main\scala\week3:

`package week3
    class Rational(x: Int, y: Int) {
        def add(that: Rational) = this + that
        def add2(that: Rational) = this + that
        ...
    }`

I then have a week3.sc scala worksheet which has the following:

`import week3.Rational
    object scratch {
      var r = new Rational(1, 2)
      var t = new Rational(3, 4)
      r < t
      t.add(r)
      t.add2(r)
    }`

There aren't any errors while compiling but on running the worksheet I get this error on the add2 method and not the add method: 

    `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: week3.Rational.add2(Lweek3/Rational;)Lweek3/Rational;
        at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(week3.sc:4)`

I have tried rebuilding the project and can even see the string add2 in the Rational.class compiled file.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem exists in 2018.1 where it requires a restart after each edit to the Rational class. Upgrading to 2018.2 fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your example and I could reproduce the exact same error you mention on a newly created project.

[image: first image]

[image: second image]

I tried both creating a dummy week3 class both in the worksheet and out of it, but nothing seemed to face IntelliJ. The problem went away when I tried to compile it using IntelliJ's built in compile button.

My first guess was that the internal compiler isn't fully kicked in until you tell it so (not by the worksheet play button at least, regardless of whether in REPL or interactive mode). Stopping the compiler and clearing the caches and trying again surprisingly made it work, which makes me believe this is a bug in the worksheet running code.

Anyways, hope I helped.

Comment: where can I find this "built in compile button"?

Comment: It's usually on the top right and has a green arrow pointing downward on it, with 1's and 0's. It says "Build project" if you hover over it. If you have a mac the shortcut is cmd+F9 (cmd key + fn key + F9 key)

Comment: I've tried that and the Build=>Rebuild Project but still no luck

Comment: Have you tried `File | Invalidate Caches` and tried recompiling? I'm guessing your structure is similar than mine? If invalidating the caches still doesn't work, I suggest you delete the `.idea` folder and re open the project (as if it was a new one)

Comment: Restarting intelliJ works but only once. So upon restarting if I add a new function to Rational I get the same error. Using 2018.1. Can you try and see if that behaviour is the same for you?

Comment: upgraded to 2018.2 and the problem went away. Thanks for your help @FSB

Comment: Adding a function to Rational doesn't change the behavior for me, but I'm using 2017.3. Maybe refactor the code into another directory? Your would basically try to get a workaround this particular bug